# Remove Spaces in between characters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a column in a table with values like these:

```
Table1
----------
H e l l o !   W o r l d 
H e l l o   e v e r y o n e ! 
H o w   a r e   y o u ?
```

Basically, there is a space (1 space) per character per record.
How can we remove the spaces like this below?

```
Table1
----------
Hello! World
Hello everyone!
How are you?
```

**Note**: we cannot remove the spaces between words like "how"-**space**-"are"-**space**-"you".

Comment: First replace triple space with some strange character never used, then replace all space with nothing, and finally replace that strange character with a single space.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [named capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) if you want to solve it via regex. Simply, `regexp_replace( VALUE, '(.) ', '\1' )`:

```
with TABLE1 as (
  select 'H e l l o !   W o r l d ' as VALUE from dual union all
  select 'H e l l o   e v e r y o n e ! ' from dual union all
  select 'H o w   a r e   y o u ? ' from dual
)
select VALUE, regexp_replace( VALUE, '(.) ', '\1' ) as REPLACED_VALUE
from TABLE1
```

Result:

```
VALUE                          REPLACED_VALUE
H e l l o !   W o r l d        Hello! World
H e l l o   e v e r y o n e !  Hello everyone!
H o w   a r e   y o u ?        How are you?
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7424/0).

Answer (score 2):

One way to do in `SQL` .

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('H e l   World','  ','#'),' '),'#',' ') from dual;
```

Comment: @Mariano no this is right. Default is null. `'' `is optional

Comment: Oh, my bad. I didn't know that.. learnt something new today. Thanks